# Login and Authentication in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, web-services, authentication

I have a web application made purely using AngularJS. I retrieve the data for each user from a web service that requires an ID and the Password of the user. The web service, if the correct ID and password are provided, returns the data of that certain user. How can I implement a log in and secure authentication using the same username and password?  Moreover, I would also want to open and close the session, which could expiry after a certain period of time.

I was thinking of using Firebase for authentication, but I am not completely sure how would I integrate that web service with Firebase, and do the authentication using the id and password already existing in the database.

Comment: Please include the code of what you have tried so far, where you are having trouble, etc. We are not going to write your code for you.

Comment: I am not really asking for the code, I am more looking for a suggestion as what technologies could I use, where to start, and what would fit best with what I have.